# Xelement tags issue

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

`enter code here`hey guys im having trouble with xelement when im trying to open the test page an unhandled exception appears and that because the

---

tag doesn't match the  closing in another line i tried to add the closings tag but the error happens before the adding function could work

test page http://densetsu.org/PP2012/benchmark1.html

so is there is a way to pass the tag problems without losing the tag effect
this is the main code:

```
             XElement tree = XElement.Load(toolStripTextBox1.Text);  
             String s = tree.ToString();  
             textBox1.Text = String_dealer.addmissing(s);
```

this is the string changer

```
        public static String addmissing(String txt)
    {
        if (txt.Contains("<br>") || (txt.Contains("</br>")))
        {
            txt.Replace("<br>", "<br></br>");
            txt.Replace("</br>", "<br></br>");
        }
        else if (txt.Contains("<hr>") || (txt.Contains("</hr>")))
        {
            txt.Replace("<hr>", "<hr> </hr>");
            txt.Replace("</hr>", "<hr> </hr>");
        }

        return txt;
    }
```

and the problem text : 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: The 'hr' start tag on line 8 does not match the end tag of 'br'. Line 9, position 10.

Comment: can you show the code as well

Comment: i did it the code that i have trouble with is here alongside with the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a stream reader from a web request then storing the stream into an String file after that you can pass the string to  sgml.reader which will transform the html into valid xml